# scala type mismatch Higher kinded type

Tags: scala, type-mismatch, higher-kinded-types, type-alias

I would like to model a `Mapper`that takes in a container of `A`s (`T[A]`) so that with a function of `f: A => B` we get another container `T[B]`. I have, after many hours of experimentation (see commented code) come up with the following solution:

```
  sealed trait Mapper[ A, T[ A ], B ] {
    //type Out <: T[B]
    type Out[X] //= T[X]
    def map( l: T[ A ], f: A => B ): Out[B]
  }

  object Mappers {

    implicit def typedMapper[ A, T[ A ] <: Iterable[ A ], B ]: Mapper[ A, T, B ] =
      new Mapper[ A, T, B ] {
        override type Out[X] = Iterable[X]
        //override type Out <: Iterable[ B ]
        //def map( l: T[ A ], f: A => B ) : this.Out = {
        def map( l: T[ A ], f: A => B ) : Out[B] = {
          println( "map" )
          l.map( f )
        }
      }

    implicit def IntMapper = typedMapper[Int, List, Int]
  }

  //def testMapper[ A, T[ A ], B ]( l: T[ A ], f: A => B )( implicit mapper: Mapper[ A, T, B ] ): T[B] = {
  def testMapper[ A, T[ A ], B ]( l: T[ A ], f: A => B )( implicit mapper: Mapper[ A, T, B ] ) : Mapper[A, T, B]#Out[B]= {
    println( mapper )
    mapper.map(l, f)
  }
```

I can now use it as follows:

```
import Mappers.IntMapper
val l9 = testMapper( List( 1, 2, 3 ), { x: Int => x + 1 } )
println(l9)
```

Although it works I am still a loss as to how I can directly restrict the Out to `T[B]`. If I do that I always seem to get a type mismatch. Can anyone point out a cleaner/simpler way of doing this without the type alias or using `T[B]` directly?

TIA

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't compile, can you post a version that does?

Comment: You are providing a specific implementation of what is called a ''Functor'' in category theory. There is a widely used library called "scalaz", as well as "cat". For a good summary, check out http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/functors-and-things-using-scala/index.html

Comment: `Mapper` is not `Functor`: you can restrict the possible `A`s and `B`s, while `Functor` must work for all `A` and `B`. This makes this a whole lot less useful in some cases, but I guess there must be some use for it.

Comment: I think the reason you get a type mismatch is that when you `map` `A => B` over `T[A]` where `T[A] <: Iterable[A]`, you don't get a `T[?]` back; you get an `Iterable[B]`. You lose knowledge about the original `Iterable`, so the default `Out = T[A]` doesn't work.

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco Apologies for that. Code is corrected. Jist uncomment the line `type Out[X] //= T[X]`

Comment: @BobDalgleish That may be too much for me. I am trying to understand how type-level programming works and want to keep stuff as simple as possible. Thanks for the pointer though.

Comment: @HTNW Exactly. I would have though the type checker would have been able to bind T[B] to Iterable[B]. Note: I think you meant `Out = T[B]` and not `Out = T[A]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a commented first approximation to what you want. The type members have been eliminated, revealing a slightly deeper problem in what you want to do.

```
trait Mapper[A, T[_], B] {
  def map(ta: T[A])(f: A => B): T[B]
}

// Note that Iterable[A]#map has type [B](A => B)Iterable[B]. You can't have typedMapper
// like yours from above just yet, because T#map is not certain to return another T;
// it only promises an Iterable.
implicit def iterableMapper[A, B]: Mapper[A, Iterable, B] = new Mapper[A, Iterable, B] {
  // Multiple param lists support the type inferencer
  override def map(i: Iterable[A])(f: A => B) = i.map(f)
}

// Curried and arg-swapped version of Mapper
type MapperOf[A, B] = { type l[T[_]] = Mapper[A, T, B] }
def map[A, B, T[_]: MapperOf[A, B]#l](ta: T[A])(f: A => B): T[B] = implicitly[Mapper[A, T, B]].map(ta)(f)

map(??? : Iterable[Any])(_.toString) // OK (at compile time, at least :P)
map(List(1,2,3))(_*2) // NOPE! The inferencer has already decided T = List, before
                      // looking for implicits, so the resolution fails to notice that
                      // iterableMapper would work.
map[Int, Int, Iterable](List(1,2,3))(_*2) // Works
```

This is pushing the limits of the type inferencer, which is why you need the manually specified type arguments.

Note that `Iterable` isn't really important to the collections hierarchy. It's mostly there because Java has it. In order for this to be properly generic to the collections, you need some delicious `CanBuildFrom` dark magic.

```
import collection._, generic._ // Open the gates of hell

implicit def collectionMapper[A, Coll[A] <: GenTraversableLike[A, Coll[A]], B]
    (implicit builderFactory: CanBuildFrom[Coll[A], B, Coll[B]]):
    Mapper[A, Coll, B] =
  new Mapper[A, Coll, B] {
    override def map(coll: Coll[A])(f: A => B): Coll[B] = coll.map(f)
  }

map(List(1))(_*2): List[Int] // Works
map(Seq(1).view)(_*2): Seq[Int] // Works, but note how we lose the knowledge of the view
                                // Exercise for the reader: fix that.
map(BitSet(1))(_*2): SortedSet[Int] // Works, but we lose the BitSet-ness
                                    // Another exercise: fix it.
```

Comment: I have been playing around with your first example. If I change `trait Mapper[A, T[_], B]`to trait `Mapper[A, T[A], B]`, still works as advertised. If I change `iterableMapper[ A, B ]` so that the map function has only a single parameter list, it still works (version 12.2). Now I don't understand why one should need the `type MapperOf[A, B]`. Why wont this work? `def map4[ A, B, T[_] ]( ta: T[ A ] , f: A => B ): T[ B ] = implicitly[ Mapper1[ A, T, B ] ].map( ta ) ( f )` (implicit not found). TIA

Comment: As for the solution that uses the `CanBuildFrom`, it's out of my league. I will have to learn how this works before attempting this.

Comment: MapperOf is pure sugar. You can dump it and rewrite following context bound as { type l[T[_]] = Mapper[A, T, B] }#l, but that's ugly. All it really does is curry the type level function Mapper from (*, * -> *, *) -> * to (*, *) -> (* -> *) -> *. The context bound always desugars to an implicit argument to map, (implicit $_some_garbage_internal_name$$$: Mapper[A, T, B]). The reason you get INF is because you don't know what A, T, or B are. You need the user to provide that to you as an implicit param themselves.

Comment: When you change T[_] to T[A], it has nothing to do with the outer A. You define a new A within the context of T[A].

Comment: You should give `map` two param lists because 1) it makes the syntax cleaner (`map(...) { ... )` vs. `map(..., { ... })`) 2) makes the inferencer happy (`map(..., { x => ... })` => `error: missing parameter type`, but `map(...) { x => ... }` infers `x`'s type from the type of the thing being mapped over) 3) Makes it prettier when currying (`map(...)(_)` vs. just `map(...)`.).

Comment: Oh, the \*s ruined the kind sig... \*"(\*, \* -> \*, \*) -> \* to (\*, \*) -> (\* -> *) -> \*"

Comment: Appreciate your patience. Your second comment just shows I understand less than I thought I did. In regards to the first one, I still have trouble mapping runt-time and compile-time concepts, but I sort of get it with the analogy to currying. As for the use of the two parameters, I understand now.  Thanks